# Taxonomy filter in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, view, taxonomy

I have a problem with taxonomy filter in Drupal 7.

**Description**

I have 2 vocabularies "Product Section" and "Manufacturers" with terms and Content Type - Products.
Not all manufacturers can be in Section.

On page "Section" there is taxonomy exposed filter with manufacturers. I need to view in filter only those manufacturers, which relate to current Section.

I create a subfield in Section vocabulary which connect Manufacturers vocabulary and marked in terms related manufacturers. But I can't create a filter with this field.

Maybe someone knows, how to do it or knows a module?